# SVG path border radius

Tags: css, svg, path

I could use a little help with setting border-radius on path tag. Here’s the current code and here’s the wanted result

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 80 10 A 70 70 0 1 1 23.368810393753677 38.855032339526886 L 37.52660779531526 49.14127425464517 A 52.5 52.5 0 1 0 80 27.5 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your path was just a single open curve that ran from 12 o'clock to 10 o'clock, then it would be easy.  You could just add `stroke-linecap="round"`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 80 18.75 A 61.25 61.25 0 1 1 30.45 44.00"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="17.5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, your shape is not like that.  It is an enclosed shape that runs clockwise from 12 to 10 o'clock, draws a line to the inside radius, then an anti-clockwise arc back to 12 o'clock again.  Adding rounded ends is somewhat trickier.

You'd need to add another arc where the `L` is now. And insert another one before the final `Z`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 80 10
           A 70 70 0 1 1 23.368810393753677 38.855032339526886
           A 8.75 8.75 0 1 1 37.52660779531526 49.14127425464517
           A 52.5 52.5 0 1 0 80 27.5
           A 8.75 8.75 0 1 1 80 10
           Z"></path>
</svg>
```

The line

```
L 37.52660779531526 49.14127425464517
```

gets replaced by the arc

```
A 8.75 8.75 0 1 1 37.52660779531526 49.14127425464517
```

The `8.75` is the arc radius. That is half the "thickness" of your shape. Ie. half of the 17.5 distance between your outer and inter arc.

There is no second line that closes the gap from the inner to the outer arc at 12 o'clock.  That is implicitly done by the `Z` close shape command.  So we have to add an extra arc in at the end, just before the `Z`.  It's an arc with the same radius as before that finishes at the start point of the shape (ie. the `M 80 10`).

```
A 8.75 8.75 0 1 1 80 10
```

I've done this manually for you now. It was quite easy for me because I am familiar with how SVG paths work.  If you have to do it for arbitrary paths, then that won't be quite so simple as this one turned out to be.