# Giving border-radius to svg and changing the font size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a circular progress bar. I've been able to create the progress bar but I need to at border-radius to the end and start of the progress and also change de font-size of the % number. I've searched around and in theory, the border-radius is added with stroke-linecap="round", but that doesn't seem to work for me. I haven't been able to find anything regarding the font-size.Adding a shadow to the bar would also be great, but that's not truly necessary.
I have already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079356/svg-path-border-radius) but I can't seem to get it right.

```js
    function drawProgress(percentage, element, svg) {
    if (svg) {
        svg.selectAll("*").remove();

    }
    var wrapper = element;
    var start = 0;

    var colours = {
        fill: '#3F88FB',
        track: '#DDDDDD',
        text: '#444444',
    }

    var radius = 34;
    var border = 8;
    var strokeSpacing = 4;
    var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
    var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
    var boxSize = radius * 2;
    var count = percentage;
    var progress = start;
    var step = percentage < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;

    //Define the circle
    var circle = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(0)
        .innerRadius(radius)
        .outerRadius(radius - border);

    //setup SVG wrapper
    svg = d3.select(wrapper)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', boxSize)
        .attr('height', boxSize);


    // ADD Group container
    var g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');

    //Setup track
    var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
    track.append('path')
        .attr('fill', colours.track)
        .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
        .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));

    //Add colour fill
    var value = track.append('path')
        .attr('fill', colours.fill)
        .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
        .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round');

    //Add text value
    var numberText = track.append('text')
        .attr('fill', colours.text)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '0.5rem');

    //update position of endAngle
    value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * percentage));
    //update text value
    numberText.text(formatText(percentage));}

    var svgVisitas;
    
    drawProgress(50 / 100, document.getElementById('radialprogressVisitas'), svgVisitas);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="radialprogressVisitas"></div>
```

[image]

Thank you. If you need anything else, please specify it in the comments and I'll edit the question. The project is run on Visual Basic.

Comment: what is `d3` in your code, you didn't declared that anywhere in your code

Comment: @CodeBug you are right, i forgot to include the javascript library I'm using. Edited the question.